# Ajax calender not working in IE

Tags: asp.net

I am using AJAX calender with the readonly textbox control to select the date. When I click on any date in calender it picks the date and attach it to txtFromDate. It is working correctly in FF and Chrome, but not in IE. Here is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox 
ID="txtFromDate" 
Text="From Date" 
runat="server" 
onfocus="javascript:this.value=''" 
onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='From Date';}">
</asp:TextBox>

<Ajax:CalendarExtender 
ID="txtCalendeControlExtenderFromDate" 
runat="server" 
Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
TargetControlID="txtFromDate">
</Ajax:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Internet explorer. The source of many a web developers anger issues.

Comment: I had almost the same problem with IE and then I added in my Web.config under <System.webServer><httpProtocol><customHeaders><add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE-8"/> this is disabling the Compatible mode in IE

Comment: Do yourself a favor and replace all the MS-AJAX controls with plain jQuery and jQuery plugins. Visual Studio populates new Web Projects with the jQuery library now by default. That's a pretty huge hint from M$.

Comment: And why do you forget semicolon after value in this line of code  onfocus="javascript:this.value=''; " ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your textbox  and calendarExteneder inside div tag like this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <asp:TextBox 
     ID="txtFromDate" 
     Text="From Date" 
     runat="server" 
     onfocus="javascript:this.value=''" 
     onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='From Date';}">
   </asp:TextBox>

   <Ajax:CalendarExtender 
   ID="txtCalendeControlExtenderFromDate" 
   runat="server" 
   Format="dd-MMM-yyyy" 
   TargetControlID="txtFromDate">
   </Ajax:CalendarExtender>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mohit Yes, but make position:relative for this div

Comment: I tried adding the style attribute, but it still not worked for me. :(

Comment: @Mohit Try to look in Error console with F12 Maybe the line of code onfocus event breaks javascript. Try to add semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this problem, just removed the inline script from the HTML, and it worked for me. :)